# Alguna forma en la que pueda hacer un salto de linea en este archivo?

Tags: c++, archivo

Intento que cada linea del archivo en el que guarde los datos aparezca como:

> No.|Desc       |ENE        |FEB        |MAR        |ABR        |MAY        |JUN        |JUL        |AGO        |SEP        |OCT        |NOV        |DIC
>   Leche               1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9         10        11        12
>   Carne               10        1         1         1         1         1         1         1         1         1         1         1

Pero al final sale todo en una linea:

> No.|Desc      |ENE        |FEB        |MAR        |ABR        |MAY        |JUN        |JUL        |AGO        |SEP        |OCT        |NOV        |DIC           leche               1         2         3         4         5         6    .....

uso una estructura para guardar los datos en el archivo secuencialmente pero no encuentro la forma en que pueda hacer un salto de linea por cada tanda de datos que desee colocar

aqui el codigo

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<string.h>

struct productos{
char no[10];
char desc[20];
char ene[10],feb[10],mar[10],abr[10],may[10],jun[10],jul[10],ago[10],sep[10],oct[10],nov[10],dic[10];
}prod;

FILE *arc;

void ingresar();


void main(){
int opc;
do
{
   system("cls");
   cout<<"Registros de la tienda Nueva Esperanza 2019\n";
   cout<<"Que desea Relizar?\n";
   cout<<"1) Ingresar Producto y ventas de 2019\n";
   cout<<"2) Calcular Promedio por Mes\n";
    cout<<"3) Total de ventas por mes\n";
   cout<<"4) Total de ventas por producto\n";
   cout<<"5) Producto mas vendido en todos los meses\n";
   cout<<"6) Salir\n";
   cout<<"Ingrese dato aqui----->";
   cin>>opc;
   switch(opc){
      case 1:
        ingresar();
      break;
      case 2:

      break;
      case 3:

      break;
      case 4:

      break;
      case 5:

      break;
      case 6:

      break;
      default:
      system("cls");
      cout<<"Ingrese una opcion Valida\n";
      system("pause");
      break;
   }
   }while(opc!=6);
   system("pause");
}

void ingresar(){

char prim[]="No.|Desc       |ENE        |FEB        |MAR        |ABR        |MAY        |JUN        |JUL        |AGO        |SEP        |OCT        |NOV        |DIC";

arc=fopen("ventas.dat","r+b");
int inicio=1;
if(!arc){
arc = fopen("ventas.dat", "w+b");
fwrite (prim, sizeof(char), sizeof(prim), arc);
}

cout<<"Ingrese producto: ";
cin>>prod.desc;
cout<<"Ingrese ganancias enero: ";
cin>>prod.ene;
cout<<"Ingrese ganancias febrero: ";
cin>>prod.feb;
cout<<"Ingrese ganancias marzo: ";
cin>>prod.mar;
cout<<"Ingrese ganancias abril: ";
cin>>prod.abr;
cout<<"Ingrese ganancias mayo: ";
cin>>prod.may;
cout<<"Ingrese ganancias junio: ";
cin>>prod.jun;
cout<<"Ingrese ganancias julio: ";
cin>>prod.jul;
cout<<"Ingrese ganancias agosto: ";
cin>>prod.ago;
cout<<"Ingrese ganancias septiembre: ";
cin>>prod.sep;
cout<<"Ingrese ganancias octubre: ";
cin>>prod.oct;
cout<<"Ingrese ganancias noviembre: ";
cin>>prod.nov;
cout<<"Ingrese ganancias diciembre: ";
cin>>prod.dic;
fseek(arc,0,SEEK_END);
fwrite (&prod, sizeof(prod),1, arc);
fclose(arc);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para añadir saltos de línea puedes usar:

```
fputc('\n', arc);
```

Que en tu caso podría quedar así:

```
fputc('\n', arc);
fwrite (&prod, sizeof(prod),1, arc);
```

Por cierto, nota que `fseek` aquí no tiene sentido porque en ningún momento estás escribiendo en una parte del fichero que no sea el final del mismo.